# Angular - access component that is a child of a third-party component

Tags: angular, viewchild

I'm aware of the `@ViewChild` and `@ContentChild` annotations that can be used to inject references to a child component and projected content within a parent component. However, I'm struggling to understand how to use any of these annotations to inject a reference to a component that is a child of a third-party component used within my template.

For example, I'm using ngx-bootstrap's `accordion` component to display some information in an accordion.

```
<accordion>
    <app-employee-details #employeeDetails>
    </app-employee-details>
</accordion>
```

I'm trying to obtain a reference to #employeeDetails, but `@ViewChild("employeeDetails")` doesn't work because it is a child of the third party `<accordion>` component.

Comment: Cant reproduce, works fine with ViewChild: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tq7noi?file=app/basic.html

Comment: That is interesting, thanks @enno.void. I'll revisit my code to see if I'm doing something else wrong.